# Max sum of matrix each element from distinct row and column

Tags: c++

I've got a problem that I couldn't handle on my own. The issue is that I need to find max sum of matrix elements such that each is from different column and row. 
Example:

{[1,**5**,2],

[0,3,**2**],

[**9**,0,1]}

The output for this matrix would be 5+2+9=16.
I know that there are some algorithms that could solve it but I'm not on this level yet so
I want to solve it by bruteforce but I don't really know how. If you could give me some tips or pseudocode I`d be really grateful.

_________________EDIT_____________

If anyone has the same issue and wants to implement algorithm for next permutation without using STL, I leave you this article, which has helped me a lot. https://www.programcreek.com/2014/06/leetcode-next-permutation-java/

Comment: Create a container with values `a = {0, ..., n-1}`. Calculate the sum `matrix[0][a[0]] + ... + matrix[n-1][a[n-1]]` for all permuations of `a`. Take the largest value.

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: Do you know how to find the maximum element of a row? Repeat that for all rows and take the sum.

Comment: @Botje you missed *from different column and row*, so is not the just the max on each

Comment: you have to choose between c and c++, remove one tag

Comment: @Ôrel I`ve calculated how many permutations I need to check, for matrix 3x3 its 3!. I created 2 variables one that will be an answer and one that is sum of current permutation. But I don`t really know how to iterate through it while making sure that I don`t add values from the same row or column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way to solve this task with brute force is:

1. Set `result = MIN`
2. Create a container with values `a = {0, ..., n-1}`
3. Calculate the `sum = matrix[0][a[0]] + ... + matrix[n-1][a[n-1]]`
4. Set `result` to `max(result, sum)`
5. If there is another permutation of `a`, permute `a` and go to 3.
6. Return `result`

STL will make your life much easier with [std::next_permutation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation), [std::max](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max), [std::iota](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota), [std::accumulate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate), [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), [std::array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array), [std::numeric_limits](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits) ...

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I've still got some questions. Is 'a' a container of all values from matrix? And second one is how could I permute by own implementations instead of STL.

Comment: `a` is container with numbers `{0, 1, 2, 3, ..., n}`, e.g. for a 3x3 matrix `a` is `{0, 1, 2}`. _"how could I permute by own implementations instead of STL"_. That's not simple. It's even more complex than this algorithm.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for your attention and help.